# Azure Artifacts updating credentials with vsts-npm-auth

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, azure-artifacts, .npmrc

I try to update my azure artifact and received the next error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="https://pkgsprodsbr1.app.pkgs.visualstudio.com/"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jicar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-30T14_59_55_304Z-debug.log
```

Try to regenerate my credentials and received:

```
vsts-npm-auth v0.41.0.0
-----------------------
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

My .npmrc file contains the exactly (copy-paste) the given from azure.
[npmrc-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNCrJ.png)

any ideas?????

Answer (score 4):

OK guys, after a couple of hours of trying different things i modify my url to

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/sisorg/Agilis.Common/_packaging/agilis-common/npm/registry
```

**without the last slash (/)** even though in the azure panel it shows it **WITH** the slash..

Comment: Thanks @Juan, Exactly this was the issue, but it was working fine before